# How to assign value to one-to-one field in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm just start learning about django and trying to assign value to one-to-one field in my models using manage.py shell. I try to do this way but not sure why it doesn't assign the value to Author.address

```
author1 = Author.objects.get(first_name="Sam")
addr1 = Address.objects.get(post_code="12345")
author1.address = addr1
```

Any missing step i missed?

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name()


class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.street}"
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you save the `author1.save()` after adding the address?

Comment: yeah. i have 2-3 sample row of data for both Author and Address. I just want to assign them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the model after assignment

```
author1 = Author.objects.get(first_name="Sam")
addr1 = Address.objects.get(post_code="12345")
author1.address = addr1
author1.save()
```

Also you can update 1-to-1 relation with [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) method

```
addr1 = Address.objects.get(post_code="12345")
Author.objects.filter(first_name="Sam").update(address=addr1)
```

Comment: Thankss, I totally missed out .save() operation. <3

Comment: @onepiece94 I'm happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I got this error. can you advise? I created Profile for User
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_profile_user_id_key"

Answer (score 0):

3 methods available
Here is example.

```
found = User.objects.get(email=obj.email) if not obj.email is None else None
if found and obj.user is None:

        #method 1found = User.objects.get(email=obj.email) if not obj.email is None else None
if found and obj.user is None:
    #method 1
    Profile.objects.filter(pk=obj.id).update(user=found)  
        
    #method 2
    obj.user = found                  
    obj.save(update_fields=['user'])  
        
    #method 3
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users_profile SET user_id = %s WHERE id = %s", ( found.id, obj.id ) )
```